# Formatting date column to row numbered (left side) column in dataframes in r

Tags: r, dataframe, date, formatting, columnsorting

I have a problem where the dates are in column 1 of my first dataframe. I want them in the column with the row numbers like my second dataframe. Below is the dput code.

---

The two **dput** codes below show two different date settings. One of the dataframe settings show the dates that I have in column1 and the second dataframe has setting which what I want. The date column is in with the number columns and there is no title column for date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to convert the dataframe into `xts` object. If the first dataframe is called `df1` you can convert the `Date` column to date class and do :

```
df2 <- xts::xts(df1[-1], as.Date(df1$Date))
df2

#            CC1G   HYLA   IHHG
#2020-10-27 21328 545.65 473.52
#2020-10-28 20915 539.00 469.95
#2020-10-29 21050 538.10 469.55
#2020-10-30 20723 538.15 470.90
#2020-11-02 21305 539.00 471.82
#2020-11-03 21430 544.35 474.60
#2020-11-04 21938 549.40 480.95
#2020-11-05 22048 555.50 482.80
#2020-11-06 22043 555.15 481.97
#2020-11-09 22693 562.50 486.05
#2020-11-10 22555 557.10 483.95
#2020-11-11 22928 556.45 483.67
#2020-11-12 22860 554.90 470.77
#2020-11-13 22360 555.60 470.80
```